# Show that the set of all $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cdot X\geq c$ is convex i.e. half planes are convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, solution-verification

Show that the set of all $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cdot X\geq c$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is convex i.e. show any half plane is convex.

Pf:

Let $S:=\{X:A\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\} \wedge A\cdot X\geq c\}$ and let $X_1,X_2\in S$. That is, assume $$A\cdot X_1\geq c\space\text{ and } A\cdot X_2\geq c$$

Now consider the line segment between $X_1,X_2$: $$(1-t)X_1+tX_2\space\text{ where $0\leq t\leq1$}$$ First observe $(1-t)X_1+tX_2\neq0$ for all $t$ since $X_1,X_2\neq0$ and $1-t$ and $t$ are never zero simultaneously. Now we show if $X(t)=(1-t)X_1+tX_2$, then $$A\cdot\left((1-t)X_1+tX_2\right)\geq c\implies X(t)\in S\space\text{for all $t$}$$

$$\iff (1-t)A\cdot X_1+tA\cdot X_2\geq(1-t)(c)+t(c)=c$$

Thus since the line segment joining any two points of $S$ is contained in $S$, we conclude $S$ is convex.

Is this an okay proof?

Comment: It seems that you are proving ``any half-space is convex''. But why you excluded the origin $\boldsymbol{0}$ from $S$?

Comment: @Ze-NanLi That was the assumption given in the question. We are to assume $A$ is a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $c$ being a fixed number.

Comment: It's not true that any line segment *containing* points from $S$ is in $S$; what's true is that any line segment *joining* points from $S$ is in $S$.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate I see that we assume $A$ is a nonzero vector but it does not mean that $S$ could not contain the origin.

Comment: @GerryMyerson isn't that what I'm constructing when I say: let $X(t)=(1-t)X_1+tX_2\text{ for $t\in[0,1]$ }$ be the line segment joining $X_1$ to $X_2$?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to understand is if my written proof of the above statement is correct or not, and what I need to do to fix it otherwise.

Comment: The argument is fine. You haven't proved that any line segment **containing** points from $S$ is in $S$, but you don't need that. What you need is that any line segment **joining** points from $S$ is in $S$, and that, you have proved.

Comment: OH! I see what you mean, I think I have fixed some of the language at the end of my post to reflect that. Thank you!

Comment: @upanddownintegrate. The set $S$ should be defined by $S = \{X: A\cdot X \ge c\}$ rather than excluding the origin. Assuming the $A$ could not be vector $\boldsymbol{0}$ is correct, but we could not assume the set $S$ does not contain the origin.

Comment: Ah. I see now, @Ze-NanLi. I have edited to reflect this